# git: how to merge directly from github without first merging to local branch

Tags: git

When I want to merge to a local branch I do this:

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master
git checkout my_branch
git merge master
```

Is there a way to merge from the master on the repository into my local my_branch without first pulling into my local master?

I tried git merge origin/master but that did not pick up commits that were on the repository but not in the local master.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
git checkout my_branch    
git pull origin master
```

Update: I didn't understand you needed also local changes. For that you can also merge them with.

```
git merge master
```

Comment: I don't care about the local changes - I want the changes on the repo merged. The 'git pull origin master' appears to have done what I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You need to update the state of the remote branch before you do your `git merge`.

The following should work for you (assuming you are on my_branch):

```
git fetch
git merge origin/master
```

This will update with the information from the remote with the commits that are not yet in your local master.  Then you can merge the remote branch into my_branch.

Comment: This worked, but I'm not sure what side effects it had. When I did the fetch I got 40 messages like: " * [new branch]      EventsTable -> origin/EventsTable" I don't know exactly what that did, but I didn't want to make any changes anywhere other then to the branch I was on (my_branch).

Comment: Those are other remote branches that are available on your remote.  Your local repository just was becoming aware that they exist on your remote.  No changes were made to your local branches.  To not have this happen just use `git fetch origin master`, this will only get the updates for the master branch.

Comment: When I did the 'git merge origin/master' after the 'git fetch origin master' it said my branch was Already up-to-date. But there are changes in master (on the repository, but not in he local master) not in my branch that I'm trying to get.